# Resteasy Authorization design - check a user owns a resource

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, resteasy, interceptor

I have a web service using Resteasy and running on Wildfly.

Authentication works by having the user pass an Authorization header with each request. Ideally, I need to check if the user owns the resource they are trying to access, but I am wondering what the best, or neatest way to do it is.

For example, a user owns several "gift lists". I have an endpoint, www.example.com/api/giftlist/7 which should retrieve a gift list with ID 7, but only if the authorization header is from the owner of that list. In code, it looks like this:

```
 /**
 * Retrieve a list by it's ID and return in JSON format.
 * @param id the ID of the list to return
 * @return the list.
 */
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@ApiOperation(value = "Get a gift list by ID.", response = GiftList.class)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public GiftList getGiftListById(@HeaderParam("Authorization") String authorization, @PathParam("id") Long id){
    User user = null;
    AccessToken token = dao.find(AccessToken.class, authorization);
    if(token !=null){
        user = token.getUser();
    }

    GiftList giftList = dao.find(GiftList.class, id);
    if(giftList == null){
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    if(!giftList.isOwnedBy(user)) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN);
    }

    return giftList;
}
```

Note nearly all of this method is to do with identifying if the user exists, and if they own the resource they are trying to access. This logic then needs repeating for PUT, POST and DELETE and it all gets rather messy.

I attempted to use an interceptor, and doing that I am able to check the role of a user, but I would not be able to get access to the type, or ID of the resource they are trying to access. Note that GiftLists are not the only resource in this application. I'm looking for a neater way to avoid doing this for every operation on most resources. Perhaps using an interceptor, but I'm not sure how I access the @PathParam values and get the correct type to then retrieve it from the database and check ownership.

This must be a common problem so I am sure there is some commonly used convention or pattern? I've done endless googling about authentication and using interceptors, but none seem to actually help with this "ownership" kind of problem.

One way to reduce *some* but not all of the mess would be to use an interceptor to take requests and find the user in the interceptor, but then I'm not sure how to pass that user object from there into the method itself to save looking it up again.

Another idea was I could pass the User, or the Authorization header to the DAO and have the DAO throw an exception if the user is not authorized to access a particular resource, but does the logic for security live in the DAO areas - this doesn't seem right either (to me) - e.g `dao.findGiftList(authorization, ID)` - but is handling this authorization the DAO's responsibility?

Comment: I should add that "no, that's perfectly normal" is a valid answer if it's correct - but I am trying to avoid repeating lots of code. There must be a much cleaner solution than this? I wanted to be able to write something like @RolesAllowed("Owner"), but of course this is the problem with the interceptor not being able to know which resource was being accessed so it cannot find if the user is, or is not the owner (Without parsing the whole request URL and running a different set of regex for each method or some horrible parsing to get the details which would be specific to each endpoint)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable authentication and authorization in your RESTful webservice, you could use [JAAS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html)

To do this on wildfly, you can:

Configure a security-domain in your Wildfly configuration, like the following one which uses a DataBase login module (in standalone.xml configuration if you run it as standalone server)

```
<security-domain name="test" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/TestDS"/>
            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from User where login = ? and (disabled is null or disabled = 0) and activated = 1"/>
            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select name,'Roles' from Role r, User_Role ur, User u where u.login=? and u.id = ur.userId and r.id = ur.roleId"/>
            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-256"/>
            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="base64"/>
            <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

Reference it in jboss-ejb3 (in case you use RESTful EJB webservices) or jboss-web.xml files in you webapp/WEB-INF directory.

*jboss-web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Configure usage of the security domain "other" -->
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>test</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

*jboss-ejb3.xml*

```
<jboss:ejb-jar xmlns:jboss="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
               xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
               xmlns:s="urn:security"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-ejb3-2_0.xsd
                         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
               version="3.1"
               impl-version="2.0">
    <assembly-descriptor>
        <s:security>
            <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>
            <s:security-domain>test</s:security-domain>
        </s:security>
    </assembly-descriptor>

</jboss:ejb-jar>
```

Configure a security-constraint and a login-config like in the following example which enables a BASIC authentication in webapp: (See [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/security-webtier002.htm) for details)

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>REST services</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/rs/user/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>TestRealm</realm-name>
</login-config>

...

<security-role>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Then annotate your REST methods with @PermitAll or @RolesAllowed to allow public access or authorized access only for some Roles, like in this example:

```
@Path("/giftlists")
public class GiftLists{

    @Resource
    private SessionContext sessionContext;

    @GET
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @RolesAllowed(USER) // Allow only authenticated users to access this
    @Path("/{giftListId}")
    public void getGiftListById(@NotNull @PathParam("giftListId") Long giftListId) {

        User user = userDAO.findUserByLogin(sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName());

        GiftList giftList = giftListDAO.findGiftListByIdAndUser(giftListId, user); // user is provided to your DAO method / query, so giftList is returned only when User owns it. (No FORBIDDEN error)

        if(giftList == null){
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
        }

    }
}
```

So with this example you have two improvements:

- You are able to restrict access to this service to authenticated users only, having role "USER" for sample.
- You can programmatically retrieve user and related roles using sessionContext. You could eventually categorize your giftLists to make them available to specific roles.

Comment: Hi. Many thanks for the reply - I do really appreciate it. This setup specifies roles, so as you have in your example, "ADMIN". It's not really a role that i'm after. As, for example, a person may be the "owner" of one list, but that does not make them an "owner" of all lists (His role is not "owner"). Do you know a way to specify that a user owns a resource, and another user (With the same role in the system) does not?

Comment: Hi, I've completed my answer with an example of service which returns a GiftList instance by Id. To my view, what you describe has to be handled programmatically (like I did in the example with fewer code lines thanks to JaaS), as the relationship between a user and its giftLists is part of your model and as you said it's not really related to authorization.

Comment: Hi Remi. This actually has a few things in it which I hadn't though of and that I can now go and look into, so this has certainly put me on the right track to implementing it. Thank you so much for your help, and I hope this post also guides some other people with similar problems. It'll take me a while to learn about JAAS

Comment: I do not see the isOwnedBy check in Rémi's implementation ? Role based authorization do not seem too complicated. Clean fine grained Owner based authorization seems much more complex...